# XCode 15.01 and iOS 17 Build Failure - React native applicaton

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, yarnpkg, ios17, xcode15

When I download iOS 17 simulator, install it, and try to build, my macbook pro i5 will restart in the middle of the build. After re-opening xcode, this strange bug appears.

XCode asks me to download iOS 17 again, while saying it is already downloaded in the platforms as a duplicate version. I have to delete the existing iOS17 simulator from disk to redownload it again.

When running build Documentation, I am met with varying errors of glog, fmt, abseil, and librarydb having extractAPI unable to find import header errors.

I have tried resetting my cocoapods to a previously compatible version of 1.13.0 and ruby 3.1.2. I have tried updating my whole system to use the newest version of cocoapods 1.14.3 and ruby 3.2.2.

After days of debugging and managing version compatibility, I was met with no change.